# I want to replace double punctuations with space

Tags: r, regex, corpus, punctuation

I wrote the following code but it does not work

```
replacePunctuation <- function(x) {
                gsub("[[:punct:]]+" , " " , x)
                }

sms_data_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_data_corpus_clean, replacePunctuation)
**I installed and loaded the library tm
```

NOTE: The purpose is to avoid punctuations like the following example:

```
Are you still.....there?
```

Using

```
sms_data_corpus_clean <- tm_map(sms_data_corpus_clean, removePunctuation)
```

We will have as result the two words to be connected like this

```
   Are you stillthere
```

Comment: I copied your function _as it appears in the question_ then `X = "Are you still.....there?"` when I run `replacePunctuation(X)` I get 
[1] "Are you still there "  The words are not joined.

Comment: May be you can try `gsub("[[:punct:]]{2,}"," ","Are you still.....there?")

[1] "Are you still there?"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `stringr`'s `str_replace` function here -

```
library(stringr)

replacePunctuation <- function(x){
  # if there are multiple punctuations replace them
  str_replace(x, pattern = "[[:punct:]]{2,}", " ")
}

sample_data <- c("2 or more punctuations - Are you still.....there?", 
                   "only one punctuation - Are you still, here?")


replacePunctuation(sample_data)
#> [1] "2 or more punctuations - Are you still there?"
#> [2] "only one punctuation - Are you still, here?"
```

Created on 2018-08-23 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).